# How to create hyperlink using XSLT with changed/limited text

Tags: html, xslt

Using the construction

```html
<a href="{@href}"><xsl:value-of select="@href"/></a>
```

leads for example to a translated result like:

```html
<a href="https://any.website.nl/datafeeds/with/a/considerable/long/tekst/string/">https://any.website.nl/datafeeds/with/a/considerable/long/tekst/string/</a>
```

The string/url is placed in a table cell. I want to limit the space. For this reason I want to  split up the text showing part (so the part after te ">"). Spliting up could be done by changing all "/" with a space. How do i arrange this?

Comment: You can use the `translate()` function to change all "/" characters to spaces - if that's what you want.

Comment: Could be the solution, how do i change the xslt rule?

Comment: Instead of `<xsl:value-of select="@href"/>` use `<xsl:value-of select="translate(@href, '/', ' ')"/>`.

Comment: Great! this solved the problem.